# Time Stamp Script not working on Pasting/Dragging Cell Values

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which records the time stamp on which an entry is made in a specific cell. It uses a onEdit trigger.

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

When I'm dragging/copy-pasting the data over a range of adjacent cells(in the same column), only the first entry is producing a time-stamp output.

CODE:

```
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 8 && sName == 'Processing') { //which column to watch on which sheet
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('CU' + row.toString()).setValue(time); //which column to put timestamp in
  };
 };
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you maybe explain what is what you expect with an example?
In the end you are only changing one cell, look at the [`getActiveCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell) documentation. Could you maybe use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) to retrieve the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using onEdit to insert a timestamp when a field is edited. But when an edit is done by copy/paste or dragging a cell/range, the timestamp is applied only for the first cell in the new target range.

The reason that this is happening is that your script output recognises only the **`activecell`** and does not recognise the rest of the `activerange`

`var r = s.getActiveCell();
var row = r.getRow();`

There are several solutions to your problem.

**ActiveRange**:
Enable the script to process the number of rows in the active range.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();

  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var ar = s.getActiveRange();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the active range = "+ar.getA1Notation()+", the number of rows = "+ar.getNumRows());
  var time = new Date();

  if( r.getColumn() == 8 && sName == 'Processing') { //which column to watch on which sheet
   // loop through the number of rows
    for (var i = 0;i<arRows;i++){
      var rowstamp = row+i;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('CU' + rowstamp.toString()).setValue(time); //which column to put timestamp in
    }
  }
 }
```

---

**Event Objects**: Enable the script to take advantage of the event Objects generated by OnEdit.

In the following script, the *edited range*, the *column*, *sheet name*, the *starting and ending row numbers* are all obtained/determined by using [Event Objects available to onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(event)); //DEBUG

  var ecolumnStart = event.range.columnStart;
  var erowStart = event.range.rowStart;
  var erowEnd = event.range.rowEnd;
  var ecolumnEnd = event.range.columnEnd;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Range details - Column Start:"+ecolumnStart+", Column End:"+ecolumnEnd+", Row start:"+erowStart+", and Row End:"+erowEnd);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the sheet is "+event.source.getName()+", the range = "+event.range.getA1Notation());
  var sName = event.range.getSheet().getName();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the sheet name is "+sName)

  var time = new Date();
  var numRows = event.range.rowEnd -event.range.rowStart+1;

  if( event.range.columnStart == 8 && sName == 'Processing') { //which column to watch on which sheet
    // loop though the number of rows
    for (var i = 0;i<numRows;i++){
      var row = event.range.rowStart+i;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time); //which column to put timestamp in
    }
  }
}
```