# onEdit Not Working When I Copy&Paste Values in Multiple Cells at Once

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, copy-paste

(This is a follow up question of - [How to Run Script on Multiple Spreadsheet Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686305/how-to-run-script-on-multiple-spreadsheet-tabs/66708491?noredirect=1))

**My question:**
When I'm dragging/copy-pasting the data over a range of adjacent cells(in the same column), only the first entry is producing a time-stamp output.

**What I am doing with the script:**
I am using onEdit to help me add a timestamp in 'timestamp' column, when someone edit 'status' column (most of the time, 'status' column).
And these columns are not always side by side.

For example:

- tab "Apple", the 'status' = column Y, the 'timestamp' = column Z
- tab "Banana", the 'status' = column A, the 'timestamp' = column B

**Background of the spreadsheet I am working on:**

1. total 6 tabs in this sheet
2. every 'status' and 'timestamp' in each tabs are not in the same column
3. in some tabs, 'status' may have a different title (e.g. 'Name')

**What I found on stackoverflow so far:**

- [Time Stamp Script not working on Pasting/Dragging Cell Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735297/time-stamp-script-not-working-on-pasting-dragging-cell-values/60766551#60766551)
- [onEdit not triggering when pasting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513930/onedit-not-triggering-when-pasting-data)

Unfortunately I am too new to script and have no ideal how to fix my code after reading articles above.

**The code I am using:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
addTimestamp(e);
}
    
  function addTimestamp(e){

var row = e.range.getRow();
var col = e.range.getColumn();

 if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Apple" && col === 22 && row >= 2){
    
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,25).setValue(time);}
    
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Banana" && col === 55 && row >= 2){
    
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,56).setValue(time);}
```

Comment: @Rubén Oh! Sorry. I had edited simultaneously.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the value of `time` to the one side right of the edited cell.
- Even when the values are copied and pasted, you want to achieve this.
- You want to reflect this for the multiple tabs, and each tab is required to set the value to each column. Each column is different.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose to use `range` of the event object. The value of `range` of event object is like `"range":{"columnEnd":#,"columnStart":#,"rowEnd":#,"rowStart":#}`. I thought that this might be used.
- In order to manage the conditions for the multiple tabs, I would like to propose to use an object. The key and value are the sheet name and the cheking column number, respectively.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your function of `addTimestamp` as follows. Please copy and paste the following script and save it. When you use this script, please edit the cell and copy and paste the values to the checking column of the sheet. By this, the script is run.

```
function addTimestamp(e) {
  var obj = {"Apple": 23, "Banana": 55}; // Please set your condition. The key and value are the sheet name and the cheking column number, respectively.

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var rowStart = range.rowStart;
  var rowEnd = range.rowEnd;
  var columnStart = range.columnStart;
  var columnEnd = range.columnEnd;
  if (obj[sheetName] && columnStart == columnEnd && columnStart == obj[sheetName] && rowStart >= 2) {
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');
    sheet.getRange(rowStart, obj[sheetName] + 1, rowEnd - rowStart + 1).setValue(time);
  }
}
```

- When you want to add more sheet condition, please modify `var obj = {"Apple": 23, "Banana": 55};`.

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you! This works really well! Allow me to ask one more question (sorry for being not clear in the question). Is there any way to also set a key value for cells that I want to put time value? The reason why I am asking this is because the timestamp column is not always on the right side of the edited column.

Comment: @Luuu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Is there any way to also set a key value for cells that I want to put time value?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand about your new question.

Comment: Thank you! Allow me to explain again. (I have also edited my question on top.)
I want a timestamp to be added into 'timestamp' column, when someone edit 'status' column (in some tabs, is 'name' column).
**But the point is that 'timestamp' column is not always right after 'status' column.** For example, on 'Apple' tab, 'status' column (which someone would edit) is column A, 'timestamp' column is column B.
**However** on 'Banana' tab, 'name' column (which someone would edit) is column Y, 'timestamp' is column Z.

Comment: Hi, I have just posted a new question [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792943/how-to-make-automatic-timestamp-to-be-added-into-specific-column). Kindly take a look and share your though if is possible. Thanks again for helping me with this.

Comment: @Luuu Thank you for your response. Now I posted an answer because I thought that I could understand about your new question from your posted question. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.